# in how many ways one can choose the number

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $n, m \in N \cup 0$, $-n\leq m\leq -n$ let $x_i \in R^n, i=1, \ldots, n$. Let $y_i\in\{-1,1\}, \, i=1, \ldots, n$.  In how many possibilities one can choose $x_i$ and  $y_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=m$?

Comment: sorry what? ${}{}{}$

Comment: ok, I have added it. It should be more clear now.

Comment: what is $y_i$??

Comment: Let me simplify this. $y_i$ are either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: You say that $x_i$ fixed, but then you ask about choosing $x_i$. If it is fixed, you don't get to choose it. Also, you say that $x_i \in \Bbb R^n$ for all $i$, but expect sums and differences of $n$-dimensional vectors to somehow add up to a natural number $m$??

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have been trying to simplify question.... I have corrected it now.